# Гибкая геометрическая фигура

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, svg

Ребят нужно реализовать вот такую геометрическую фигуру с тенью , и возможностью увеличения высоты без растяжек и потери качества

[image: [1]]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
div {
  margin: 15px auto;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 59, 59, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 124, 124, 1) 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25px, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 25px);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 25px, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 25px);
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #009898;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0, 152, 152, .15) 0%, rgba(0, 152, 152, .25) 50%, rgba(0, 152, 152, .15) 100%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 55px rgba(0, 152, 152, .05);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```